# SQL Relationship with Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm building out the website for my custom guitar company and I just realized there's something about the way the database will need to work that I can't seem to wrap my head around - or perhaps I'm overthinking it and confusing myself.

There are two tables I need to relate to each other: an `Artists` table and a `Projects` table. The `artists` table stores info about individual artists and the `Projects` table stores info about bands/projects.

It is easy enough to create the `Artists` table and use it's primary key as a foreign key in the `Projects` table; and if one artist were involved with multiple projects, that's no problem in that arrangement. The thing that occurs to me though, is that it is entirely possible to have one project associated with more than one artist, too.

I know it would not be consistent with the normal forms to have an `artist_id` field as a foreign key in the `Projects` table if it had multiple values (non-atomic); but I'm not sure how else I could achieve this.

It may also help to know the use-case:

I am building a Django-REST back-end, which will be consumed by an Angular front-end. There is a page with artists profiles that Angular parses from JSON using `*ngFor`. So each chunk of html added to the `DOM` with `*ngFor` will display the artists name, a bio and a picture; the projects the artist is associated with are added to the `DOM` via an inner-ngFor loop.

Here are the data structures from the Angular side:

```
import {ArtistSocialMediaModel} from './artist-social-media.model';

export class ArtistProfilesModel {
  public artist_name: string;
  public artist_image: string;
  // the second string is a range of active dates for a given project
  // which I will convert to a string in Django before serializing
  public projects: Array<[string, string]>;
  public description: string;
  public band_website: string;
  public social_media: ArtistSocialMediaModel[];

  constructor(name: string, image: string, projects,
          description: string, website: string, social) {


    this.artist_name = name;
    this.artist_image = image;
    this.projects = projects;
    this.description = description;
    this.band_website = website;
    this.social_media = social;
  }

}
```

This is the social media model you see above, but this will be a straigt forward one-to-one relationship with an `Artists_Social` table:

```
export class ArtistSocialMediaModel {
  public facebook: string;
  public twitter: string;
  public instagram: string;

  constructor(facebook: string, twitter: string, instagram: string) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
    this.twitter = twitter;
    this.instagram = instagram;
  }

}
```

This is the template that displays the data:

```
    <div *ngFor="let profile of artistProfiles; let i = index"
     class="profiles-div">

    <div *ngIf="resolveIndex(i) === 'left'; then left else right">ignored</div>

    <ng-template #left>
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6 col-md-5">

        <img [src]="profile.artist_image"
             [alt]="profile.artist_name"
             class="img-thumbnail img-fluid"
             [ngStyle]="{ 'float': resolveIndex(i)}">

        <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
            [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
          Projects:
        </h1>
        <p *ngFor="let project of profile.projects"
           [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
           class="artists-p">
          {{project[0] + ": " + project[1]}}
        </p>

        <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
            [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
          Website:
        </h1>
        <a href="https:{{profile.band_website}}"
           target="_blank">
          <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
             class="artists-p">
            {{profile.band_website}}
          </p>
        </a>

        <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
            [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
          Social Media:
        </h1>
        <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['facebook']}}"
           target="_blank">
          <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
             class="artists-p">{{profile.social_media['facebook']}}</p>
        </a>

        <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['twitter']}}"
           target="_blank">
          <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
             class="artists-p">{{profile.social_media['twitter']}}</p>
        </a>

        <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['instagram']}}"
           target="_blank">
          <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
             class="artists-p">
            {{profile.social_media['instagram']}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 col-md-7">
        <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header">{{ profile.artist_name }}
        </h1>
        <br>
        <p class="artists-p">{{ profile.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </ng-template>

   <ng-template #right>
    <div class="row ng-template-right">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-7">
        <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header">{{ profile.artist_name }}
        </h1>
        <br>
        <p class="artists-p">{{ profile.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
        <img [src]="profile.artist_image"
             [alt]="profile.artist_name"
             class="img-thumbnail"
             [ngStyle]="{ 'float': resolveIndex(i)}">

        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
              [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
            Projects:
          </h1>
          <p *ngFor="let project of profile.projects"
             [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
             class="artists-p">
            {{project[0] + ": " + project[1]}}
          </p>

          <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
              [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
            Website:
          </h1>
          <a href="https:{{profile.band_website}}"
             target="_blank">
            <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
               class="artists-p">
              {{profile.band_website}}
            </p>
          </a>

          <h1 class="artists-jumbo-header"
              [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}">
            Social Media:
          </h1>
          <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['facebook']}}"
             target="_blank">
            <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
               class="artists-p">{{profile.social_media['facebook']}}</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['twitter']}}"
             target="_blank">
            <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
               class="artists-p">{{profile.social_media['twitter']}}</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://{{profile.social_media['instagram']}}"
             target="_blank">
            <p [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align': resolveIndex(i)}"
               class="artists-p">
              {{profile.social_media['instagram']}}</p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <hr>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Django, but what you're asking about is a many-to-many relationship. In most database systems, a many-to-many is implemented via a third table with foreign keys to the tables you're linking. Some database systems allow you to store an array as a member of a row, which can be used for this. However, that's a rare thing (usually only present in hierarchical databases). The third-table approach is the most widely applicable.

In your case, your tables would look something like this. Note that the primary key of the `Artist_Projects` table is a composite key -- it's the *combination* of `artist_id` and `project_id` that is primary key. But each of those fields is a foreign key to a separate table.

```
+----------------+      +----------------------+      
| Artists        |      | Artist_Projects      |      +-----------------+
+----------------+      +----------------------+      | Projects        |
| artist_id (PK) | <--- | artist_id  (PK) (FK) |      +-----------------+
+----------------+      | project_id (PK) (FK) | ---> | project_id (PK) |
                        +----------------------+      +-----------------+
```

Comment: No need to know about Django, necessarily, I just think it's good to give lots of detail in these questions. I thought it may be a many-to-many might be the solution, but I couldn't remember exactly how to implement it. I figured I should just reach out before I got too deep and get some intelligent input. Thanks for your answer, I'll try it out in a bit, and I'm happy to upvote!

Comment: @Hildy Any luck with this. Please mark the answer if this addressed your needs.